# Simple matrix reasoning

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, matrix-rank

Im a littlebit stuck here. 
Suppose $Ax=(1,1,1)$ doesn't have any solutions, but $Ax=(0,1,0)$ has one unique  solution. How does this imply that $Ax=(0,0,0)$ has one uniqe solution?

I was thinking that if $b=(0,1,0)$, the augmented matrix $[A|b]~...~[R|c]$ where R is in RREF. Now if i replace any row of c with zero the system must still be consistent, and have a unique solution right?  Do you guys have an easier explanation?    Thanx :) (Algebra exam next week)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if $Ax=(1,1,1)$ doesn't have any solutions then $Ax=(0,0,0)$ has NOT one unique solution

Comment: Can you please explain?  This task was in a exam 2 years ago.

Comment: because if $Ax=(1,1,1)$ doesn't have any solutions then A is singular then $dim(kerA)>0$ that is: there are infinite many solution for $Ax=(0,0,0)$

Comment: To be picky, we don’t know that $A$ is a square matrix, so I don’t think it’s quite correct to call it “singular,” but it is rank-deficient.

Comment: Ok, so since A is square, Ax=(1,1,1) has a unique solution x if and only if A is row equivalent to I. But since, by hypothesis Ax=(1,1,1) doesn't have any solutions, then A is not row equivalent to I, so that Ax=0. Has infinitely many solutions because A has at least one free variable?  Like that?